# Зачем нужен IP-адрес, если есть MAC-адрес?

Tags: ip, сеть, osi

Зачем нужен IP-адрес, если есть мак адрес? Т.е. убрать 3 уровень модели OSI (машрутизацию) и сделать все по коммутаций. Либо наоборот убрать 2 уровень и оставить только 3.

Comment: Некоторые программы так и работают. По MAC-адресам. Но в пределах одного сегмента локальной сети. А вообще -- RTFM.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Коммуникацию можно устраивать и по ethernet, дело в том, что большинство программ работают с протоколом tcp/ip, так как это универсальнее. Если же вы хотите устроить коммутацию на весь интернет, то вас ждет разочарование - представьте, сколько шума будет в подобной сети, ведь без маршрутизации все пакеты, кем-либо посланные, придут ко всем участникам сети (даже если сделать что-то типа свитчей, (которые будут определять, на каком порту какой mac), то это потребует, во-первых, просто безумнейших таблиц маков по портам, а во-вторых, сеть - не иерархическая структура, т.е. нет никаких гарантий, что исходящий пакет придет только на один порт. В общем, читайте об устройстве протокола ethernet.

Убрать же 2-й уровень просто не получится, т.к. в таком случае придется анонсировать каждый адрес отдельно (скажем, мы говорим - теперь ipv6 это fe80:: и далее вычисляем из mac адреса). Т.е. мы в таком случае вынуждены вместо анонса сети анонсировать отдельный адрес, это раз, мы можем в общем-то сделать ipv6 так: ourn:etad:dres:fe80::pcma:cadd:ress, но это потребует смены всей инфраструктуры, кроме того, не избавит нас от протокола ethernet, а просто скроет его. Правда, локально, в вашем сегменте, вы конечно, сможете выдавать адреса ipv6 по dhcp, основываясь на mac address, никто вам не помешает :)

А еще бывают сети, в которых mac-адреса нет, а ip есть :) Называются point-to-point (например, по модему когда соединяемся - нет протокола ethernet).

Comment: @eicto

    Коммуникацию можно устраивать и по arp

<зануда-mode>
Интересная фраза. Воображение перенапрягает...
И исчо. ip-адрес принадлежит не компьютеру, а интерфейсу. Хост ip-адреса не имеет...
</зануда-mode>

Comment: `<ultra-зануда-mode>` не интерфейсу он принадлежит а сети, в том смысле, что интерфейс это необязательная абстракция в терминах tcp/ip, например, с помощью iproute и такой-то матери я наверное смогу сделать так, чтобы на всех интерфейсах были одинаковые ip и при этом, чтобы оно работало. Ну или вообще в воображении - некий программно-аппаратный комплекс, в котором OS вообще не будет знать о физических интерфейсах.(вот кстати программы обычно не в курсе про интерфейсы, а сетью ip пользуются)  `</ultra-зануда-mode>`

А чем фраза странная ? долго ли написать arp-чат  ?

Comment: конечно в arp можно устроить коммуникацию, но вы правы - это будет что-то типа ip over icmp

Comment: >долго ли написать arp-чат ?
Опиши алгоритм работы, и я скорее всего объясню тебе почему это нельзя назвать «arp-чат». Для справки, ARP это Address Resolution Protocol, протокол позволяющий (в рамках одного L2 сегмента) определить какой MAC-адрес (L2 адрес) имеет интерфейс на котором поднят нужный IP адрес.

Comment: у меня в юности вот такой примерно плакатик был http://www.mysoftware.ru/download/setevoy_plakat_karti_protokolov/ :) почему-то я его как-то нахаляву получил,

Comment: думаю должно хватить для установки какого угодно общения.

     whohas целых четыре байта пакета данных (даже больше, но лень думать) tells ещё и обратный адрес, 

и это широковещательно, т.е. дойдет до каждого, кто эту белеберду будет слушать.

мало того само это обнаружение адресов уже является двусторонним обменом данными :) т.е. в некотором смысле чатом.

коммуникацию можно устроить всегда, когда можно передать и получить хотя-бы один бит. естественно это всё будет протоколом поверх, т.к. сам arp делает вполне ограниченную коммуникацию, для которой предназначен.

Comment: Поразительно, до чего могут додуматься люди если их вовремя не изолировать (:

Но вообще-то это просто коммуникация на втором уровне OSI зачем-то завёрнутая другой протокол. Программам совершенно не возбраняется обмениваться любой информацией напрямую через enternet-фреймы (без помощи IP), или иные L2 кадры, но зачем.
Думаю при желании можно даже припомнить прикладные протоколы работающие по L2. Но с ходу ничего кроме wake-on-lan в голову не приходит.

Answer (score 1):

Раньше единого стандарта не было на оборудование, в частности на адресацию на физическом уровне. Нужно было ввести общий стандарт для взаимодействия между сетями, который был бы понятен всем устройствам. Так и появился IP. Многие называют его протоколом Интернета, однако правильно межсетевой протокол.

Comment: IP это в первую очередь протокол решающий задачу маршрутизации трафика. Объединение разнородных сетей пожалуй всё-таки вторично.
Протоколы второго уровня плохо работают в больших распределённых сетях.

Comment: Маршрутизацией занимаются RIP, OSPF. IP это обертка, содержащая просто адреса отправителя и получателя. А уж каким маршрутом он пойдет, IP никак не регламентирует.

Comment: @aleksandr_mai,

читайте на тему "маршрутизируемые протоколы" и "протоколы маршрутизации". Если маршрутутизация статическая (static), то никаких RIP-ЩЫЗА может и не требоваться. И к тому же эти протоколы маршрутизации - для небольших сетей.

Comment: @aleksandr_mai, протоколы динамической маршрутизации (RIP, OSPF, EIGRP и прочие BGP) по сути просто средства автоматизации наполнения таблицы маршрутизации. За саму маршрутизацию отвечает протокол IP. Протокол IP это не только IP-пакет, это ещё и правила обращения с ним.

Comment: @MrClon, когда отправляется письмо почтой России, например, Вы вкладываете в конверт (IP-пакет). Пишите свой адрес и адрес получателя. Где там управление маршрутизацией? Тоже самое с IP.

Comment: @alexlz, пакет маршрутизирует маршрутизатор. Устройство. Статические таблицы, динамические таблицы их что IP заполняет? Есть таблицы из которых маршрут получится - отлично, пакет дойдет. Нет таблицы - никуда IP-пакет не уйдет. IP задает только адреса. Всё.

Comment: @aleksandr_mai, ещё раз тебе повторяю. IP это протокол, а не только пакет. Этот протокол описывает как надлежит обрабатывать IP-пакеты.
Если так-уж хочется использовать аналогии: IP это не пакет, IP это регламент работы почты.

Comment: @MrClon смотри выше, я там уже ответил.

Comment: @aleksandr_mai, я отвечал на оба твоих сообщения. IP (протокол) это в первую очередь протокол регламентирующий поведение маршрутизаторов, то как они будут использовать информацию из таблицы маршрутизации.

Comment: @aleksandr_mai ещё немного занудства. Маршрутизатор - это устройство или программа (напр., маршрутизатор на персоналке)? А статические таблицы заполняет человек. И что?

Answer (score 0):

Рекомендую ознакомиться с этой лекцией. В неё рассматривается организация сетей именно с точки зрения решаемых задач. Как бы воссоздаётся процесс разработки сетевых протоколов. Очень интересно, на мой взгляд.

https://tech.yandex.ru/education/kit/3/talks/526/

https://tech.yandex.ru/education/kit/3/talks/527/

Comment: @MrClon, не получается там вставить комментарий, видимо перебор. Вот чтобы вбить осиновый кол, приведу цитату из стандарта IP (RFC 791): пункт 1.4. Читаем... "The internet protocol implements two basic functions:  addressing and fragmentation".

Comment: @aleksandr_mai, задача адресации решается и в L2 протоколах. А вот вменяемой маршрутизацией там и не пахнет, так как нет суммирования адресов.

Comment: @MrClon, если быть справедливым, то существуют способы маршрутизации канальных протоколов, вспомним те же бриджи поверх open-vpn или свитчи, которые составляют таблицы mac-адресов на своих интерфейсах (чем не маршрутизация?). Другое дело, что оно не очень удобно для больших сетей и будет страшно глючить там, где иерархия физических линков - не дерево.

Comment: @MrClon, так чем сам протокол arp (без всякого поверх) не коммуникация между  участниками сети? Информация передается между участниками? Протокол соблюден? Один узел получил информацию о другом? Я нисколько не сомневаюсь в вашей правоте, просто если считать строго, то до конца. А проблема создания протоколов не в том, чтобы их придумать, а скорее в том, чтобы они поддерживались кем-то, кроме того, кто придумал (ipx тому пример, он, кстати, немного похож на то, что я описывал под видом договоренности в ipv6).

Comment: @eicto, не думаю, что то, что есть на L2, можно назвать маршрутизацией. Это скорее «каждый знает каждого».

В предложенном варианте вся коммутация лежит целиком на L2, а ARP всунут между полезной нагрузкой и L2, чёрт знает зачем. Собственно уже не всунут, как я погляжу. «Коммуникацию можно устраивать и по ethernet», я счастлив.

Comment: Ну так я сразу и исправил :) Я же сказал, что согласен в целом,  в последний раз я говорил не о чате поверх arp, а о самом протоколе arp, он же суть есть коммуникация (в общем-то я не припомню двунаправленных сетевых протоколов, которые не для коммуникации):)

Comment: @MrClon, то, что на L2, называется бриджинг. Или типа того. Поскольку там маршрут в случае сложных систем свитчей/бриджей тоже надо считать. И кольца рвать, если вдруг получились.

Comment: @alexlz, кажется, это называется свичинг (коммутация).

Answer (score 0):

http://ciscotips.ru/ip-and-mac
по ссылке обстоятельный ответ на вопрос. По сути IP адрес показывает далекий пункт назначения (и исходный пункт отправления), а MAC адреса нужны для прохождения маленьких этапов, на которые делится длинный путь.

Answer (score -1):

Навеяло новым вопросом - зачем нужен ай-пи если есть мак.

TCP/IP протокол используется для передачи информации на любые короткие или длинные расстояния. TCP/IP может быть запакован в любой протокол нижнего (2-го) уровня, TCP/IP может иметь мак адрес, может не иметь.

MAC-адрес, элемент Ethernet протокола, предназначен для обмена сообщениями между узлами Ethernet - между звеньями внутри звезды. (Не дерева, а только звезды). Так как в звезду обычно обьеденяют небольшое к-во компьютеров - то чаще всего это небольшие расстояния. На большие расстояния гипотетически можно, но на практике не используют. Часто это рамки здания, рамки квартиры (если личный роутер), в некоторых случаях - компы одного провайдера определённого населенного пункта - зависит от того как настроили сеть. Чем больше звеньев у звезды тем тяжелее её настроить, и тем тяжелее заставить её эффективно работать. Поэтому большие сети бьют на несколько подсетей-звезд.

Попробую набросать схему действия сети и проиллюстрировать разницу айпи и мак-адрес (пример грубый упрощённый) с двумя звёздами вокруг свич1 и свич2.

```
 ПК1,МАК1      ПК2, МАК2 
   \            /
    свич1, МАК4   
             \
            свич2 МАК5 - ПК3, МАК3.
```

Как правило простые свичи не имеют мак-адреса. Мак-адрес используется внутри звезды, для адресации пакетов. Свич 1 знает только три мака: мак1 и мак2, мак5 и всё.  В таблице айпи-адресов записано, что если указан айпи ПК3, то надо их направлять на свич2. Свич2 знает только что у него есть МАК4, МАК2, МАК5. И так далее.

Т.е. Если нам надо отправить пакет с ПК1 на ПК3 то маршрут будет такой (грубо).

```
   Получатель: МАК4, IP-отправителя ПК1, IP-получателя-ПК3, тело пакета.
   Свич1 получил пакет, зная ай-пи поменял мак адрес:
   Получатель: МАК5, IP-отправителя ПК1, IP-получателя-ПК3, тело пакета.
   Свчи2 получил пакет, зная ай-пи поменял мак адрес:
   Получатель: МАК3, IP-отправителя ПК1, IP-получателя-ПК3, тело пакета.
```

Видим что при передаче пакет трансформировался. Кажый свич помнит откуда он получил пакет, для того что бы вернувшийся пакет преобразовать назад и вернуть мак отправителя. Смена мака происходит в обратном направлении.

Так не всегда происходит. Есть служебные пакеты, есть широковещательные пакеты, есть многопортовые свичи которые умеют внутри локальной сети минимизировать колличество перепаковок пакетов до нуля даже при работе в паре с другим свичем. Современные два свича внутри локальной сети скорее не будут на самом деле перепаковывать пакеты - это будут делать "магистральные" свичи (свичи бывают разные, програмируемые можно на два режима програмировать как на то что бы перепаковывали пакеты, так что бы не перепаковывали, выделять группы сегменты для которых свои правила), первый - который подключен к интернету (если органицация подключена), второй - на стороне провейдера, а дальше зависит от узлов к которым подключен провайдер, они могут быть раскиданы по разным уголкам мира. Но сути - мак-адрес - известен только ближайшим узлам в дереве (узлам 1-го уровня, своей "звезды").

Как правило ПК, свич, хаб - называют узлом. Веточки называют каналами. Каналом может быть как RJ45 так и "матрёшка" из других протоколов упакованая в любой другой протокол нижнего уровня (например WiFi, например особый протокол для уплотнения трафика).

Видимость в протоколах. Из протокола верхнего уровня не видно что происходит на нижнем уровне. С уровня MAC или с уровня TCP/IP информация про то, что именно внутри канала - не доступна. Есть канал - и всё. Узнать Wifi там или оптоволокно - нет заявленой возможности. То же и с TCP/IP. TCP/IP не знает ничего про МАС. Только программа (драйвер) на канальном уровне, зная IP-адрес формирует нужный МАС, используя АRP таблицу, и всё это от обычных программистов спрятано. С уровня TCP/IP управлять МАС-адресом не получится, потому что его просто ещё некуда записать.

Видимость свичей. Свичи-хабы которые наращивают звенья сети - физически образуют дерево, но логически это всёравно видится сетью как звезда. МАС адреса в таком режиме не перепаковуются, иначе это уже будет не звезда. Колличество уникальных маков в таблице ARP должно быть по колличеству конечных звеньев сети в звезде. Дополнительные деревья-невидимки, перекрёсные трафики, пропускная способность свичей при работе с большим колличеством каналов - замедляют сеть. МАС-адреса которые не принадлежат звезде - просто теряются.

**Итого**: адресовать пакеты по мак-адресу не используя протоколы верхнего уровня можно только внутри звезды. Гипотетически - если правильно настроена сеть, то внутри небольшой локальной сети (той части которая неразбита на подсети) можно передавать пакеты по мак-адресу не используя ай-пи, при условии что ПО умеет такие патеты обрабатывать и сетевое оборудывание это умеет.

**Програмы**. Скорее всего некоторые старые DOS-игры умеют коннектится без айпи (через старые сетевые карты). RAW-socket - нет (IP заголовок можно править, а MAC - нельзя). Можно через pcap-библиотеку. Скорее всего под виндой это доступно только с уровня драйвера (pcap использует драйвер), поэтому обычный софт врядли отправит. ARP-таблица доступна без особых прав. Линукс - можно. Микроконтроллеры - можно.

**Утилиты** Видимые свичи можно увидеть в командной строке, указав `tracert ip-адрес`.
Свою ARP-таблицу соответствий IP-MAC можно посмотреть командой `arp -a` (таблица бывает большой, лучше почитать справку или делать при свежеперегруженом пк). Что бы таблица "наполнилась" лучше предварительно `ping` сделать. Если у двух айпи один мак - значит там скорее всего 99% свич (ПК можно заставить тоже маршрутизировать используя спец ПО). Чужую ARP - нельзя (можно есть есть особый авторизированый доступ к свичу или ПК).

Comment: Вы не учли главное: В IP есть не только адрес узла, но и адрес сети, определяемый маской сети (более точно - комбинацией AND адреса и маски).

Благодаря этому и образуется иерархическая структура - зная адрес и маску сети конкретного узла, а также учитывая таблицу маршрутизации , можно сделать вывод о том, нужно ли направлять пакет на маршрутизатор  (и на какой), который в свою очередь может повторить ту же операцию и принять решение, куда этот пакет следует послать далее.