# Зачем нужен IP адрес, если есть mac-адресс?

Tags: сеть, подсети

Только не ругайтесь за такой, вероятно глупый вопрос, но все таки:

А зачем понадобилось вводить IP адреса ? Ведь, если я правильно понял - у каждого сетевого устройства есть mac-адресс. Почему нельзя было на канальном уровне сделать сразу протокол по типу IP-протокола, только это был бы условный MAC-протокол ?

То есть на маршрутизаторах были бы такие же таблицы соответствия mac-адрессов и роутеры знали бы куда перенаправлять каждый пакет. ?

Comment: Суть - мак-адрес используется для передачи на короткие расстояния, и не может передавать пакеты через посредника, а значит не сможет физически отправить пакет дальше первого же свича.

Comment: nick_n_a, не совсем понял, почему mac-адрес нельзя передать через посредника ? Что этому помешает ?

Comment: Учитывая, что mac-адресов может быть около 281 триллиона — таблица соответствия получится, мягко говоря, очень большой. IP-адреса привязаны по подсетям к определённым регионам и это позволяет оптимизировать таблицу, а со статическими mac-адресами такой трюк уже не прокатит

Comment: Протокол использующий исключительно МАС не предусматривает передачу пакета дальнему родственику по MAC, пакет может быть передан только знакомым девайсом доступных по ветвям первого уровня звезды. Передачу на другие уровни обеспечивают более сложные протоколы.

Comment: andreymal, то есть фактически это сделать можно, просто это будет не эффективно ?

Comment: nick_n_a, о каком протоколе Вы говорите ?

Comment: @Optimus1 вообще то свитчи и так используют mac адреса для переадресации пакетов...

Comment: Barmaley♦, да, но насколько я понимаю на свитчах есть таблица соответствия IP - mac ? Мой вопрос, как раз и был в том, что, если "вообще то свитчи и так используют mac адреса для переадресации пакетов." - то зачем им посредник в виде IP-адреса.

Comment: Свич может хранить как мак реального ай-пи, так и мак посредника. Пакет идущий от одного ПК к другому, может сменить два и более раза мак-адрес доставки. МАК-адрес, это типа как направление - у меня есть 8 дверей, ваш ай-пи в какие двери. А если нет протокола более высокого уровня, и для мака нельзя найти соответствие - то пакет ошибочный.

Comment: @Optimus1 свитчам он и не нужен, вы вполне можете избавиться от IP-адресов в пределах вашей локальной сети, если адаптируете все нужные вам программы под использование только mac-адресов (правда, это будет трудно, потому что штатные средства ОС для таких извращений не очень предусмотрены). Но для доступа к устройствам из других сетей (в том числе в интернете) уже придётся использовать IP. Ну и nick_n_a выше правильно отметил, что mac-адрес доставки действительно может меняться

Comment: Дополню - любой посредник в любом протоколе более высокого уровня - меняет мак после прохождения через себя. Поэтому не меняя мак - пакет идет до первой точки (узел) в сети. Если этот пакет предназначался этой точке (узел) - то доставлен, если нет - идет смена мак-адреса у пакета, и пакет передаётся дальше к следующему ближайшему узлу, и не как либо, а конкретно по определённой ветке (ветка = условно провод).

Comment: Где-то так https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1280858/17974